# New permission added to list. Update all users to have new permission via Trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

So I have a table with all of the reports that our in-house site has. I am trying to make a trigger so that when a new report is added to this list that all users get updated with the permission. (Default access False)

I don't full understand Triggers and have been performing this task with a couple of sql statements in conjunction with C#. Though I'm certain there is a way to do this with just an SQL Trigger.

This is the closest I have gotten thus far (Not Functioning). Names altered for Security.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [New Trigger]
    ON [dbo].[List_Table]
    FOR INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Permission_Table]
        (UserId, ReportId, Granted)
        (SELECT UserId FROM [dbo].[User_Table]),(SELECT ReportId FROM inserted),false
    END
```

The goal is for it to add a row in the permission table for each user with the list table id and the value of false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want an `insert . . . select`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [New Trigger]
    ON [dbo].[List_Table]
    FOR INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Permission_Table](UserId, ReportId, Granted)
           SELECT u.UserId, i.ReportId, 'false'
           FROM Inserted i CROSS JOIN
                [dbo].[User_Table] u;
    END
```

Comment: will this insert a row per UserId?